# Using button control in google maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using the following code to cause events based upon button clicks. When I click the button,the page reloads but no change occurs in the map

```
form action="#" onsubmit="animate();  return false"  p  inputtype="submit"value="Zoom!" /  /p  /form  function animate() {   map.setZoom(10);  }
```

Can anyone help me out with this?
Thank you

Comment: <form action="#" onsubmit="animate(); return false"> <p> <input type="submit" value="Zoom!" /> </p> </form>

Answer (score 0):

If you've got `return false`, and the page reloads, that usually implies to me that there's a javascript error.  Check the javascript error logs, or use Firebug, to see if there are errors happening.  e.g. is `map` defined as a global variable?

Comment: I found the error, map variable was not gloabl, hence the call was not able to reference it.

Comment: And can you please tell me what differences occur if I set return true or false